# How do you add a CIM instance with a key parameter that contains prohibited wildcards?

Tags: powershell, odbc, wmi, powershell-7.0

*Note: I'm aware of the [Wdac module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/wdac/?view=win10-ps) but it [currently does not work from PowerShell 7](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12427).  Working around that issue led to this question.*

---

The [Add method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wdacwmiprov/add-msft-odbcdsntask) of the MSFT_OdbcDsnTask class has a required parameter "DriverName" whose description reads as follows:

> *DriverName [in]*
>
> The name of the ODBC driver for the new ODBC DSN. You cannot use wildcard characters.

Most of the ODBC drivers on my computer have names containing `*` which, I think, is interpreted as a wildcard character in this context.  The following are some examples:

> - Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)
> - Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
> - Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)

Invoking the Add method to create a DSN by invoking the PowerShell command

```
Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName MSFT_OdbcDsnTask `
                 -Namespace ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Wdac `
                 -MethodName 'Add' `
                 -Arguments @{
                     Name       = 'test'
                     DsnType    = 'User'
                     Platform   = '32-bit'
                     DriverName = 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)'
                     # DriverName = 'SQL Server' }
```

results in the error `The requested object could not be found.`.  Changing the commented line so that `DriverName = 'SQL Server'` instead of the excel driver that contains the wildcard successfully creates a DSN.

1. How do I create a DSN using CIM/WMI for drivers with names containing wildcard characters?
2. Is there a way to refer to a driver whose name contains `*` in a manner that allows the `Add` method to find that driver?

---

Update 1:

The error generated pursuant to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398748/how-do-you-add-a-cim-instance-with-a-key-parameter-that-contains-prohibited-wild?noredirect=1#comment108695794_61398748) got me wondering whether this really was down to wildcards.  I ran [this script](https://gist.github.com/alx9r/2b4841f8e145dfebfc6ceb0c5c5aee27) to test all of the drivers mentioned on my computer.  The result is below.  Note that the driver `Microsoft ODBC for Oracle` failed with the error `The driver {ODBC for Oracle} is not installed.`.

```
Result  Name
------  ----
Failure Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)
Failure Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )
Failure Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
Failure Microsoft Text-Treiber (*.txt; *.csv)
Failure Microsoft Excel-Treiber (*.xls)
Failure Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)
Failure Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)
Failure Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)
Failure Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)
Failure Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)
Failure Microsoft ODBC for Oracle
Failure Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)
Failure Driver da Microsoft para arquivos texto (*.txt; *.csv)
Failure Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)
Failure Microsoft Access-Treiber (*.mdb)
Failure Driver do Microsoft Paradox (*.db )
Failure Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)
Failure Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)
Failure Microsoft Paradox-Treiber (*.db )
Failure Microsoft dBase-Treiber (*.dbf)
Success SQL Server Native Client 11.0
Success SQL Server
Success SQL Server
Success SQL Server Native Client 11.0
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `*` character? `'Microsoft Excel Driver (\*.xls)'`

Comment: @Theo `'Microsoft Excel Driver (\*.xls)'` results in the error "The driver is not installed."  Now I'm wondering whether the wildcard character really is the problem.

Comment: Hmmm.. it was a wild guess because I also believed the wildcard character caused the error. I hope you find a solution or someone else knows what causes this.

Comment: if this is for ps7, you may want to add that tag to your Question.